# Swipe Gesture on UITableview Cell Like Whtsapp does for "Reply a Message"

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, swipe-gesture

How can we implement swipe gesture on tableview cell and move the tableview cell as the finger moves from left to right?

I am able to add the swipe gesture but moving the cell is something I want to implement.

`Whatsapp` has the same feature implemented while replying to a message and want to attain the same animation effect.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a demo for this. You can use https://github.com/Dharmesh-shah2412/demoWhatsappSwipeToReply

Objective C :

I have added PanGesture to Tableviewcell :

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureCellAction:)];
    pan.delegate = self;
    [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)panGestureCellAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    if (recognizer.view.frame.origin.x < 0) { return; }
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x+ translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y );
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    if(recognizer.view.frame.origin.x > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.9)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [recognizer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, recognizer.view.frame.origin.y, recognizer.view.frame.size.width, recognizer.view.frame.size.height)];
        } completion:nil];
    }
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        int x = recognizer.view.frame.origin.x;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [recognizer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, recognizer.view.frame.origin.y, recognizer.view.frame.size.width, recognizer.view.frame.size.height)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (x > recognizer.view.frame.size.width / 2) {
                [_txtField becomeFirstResponder];
            }
        }];
    }
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:_tblView];
    if (velocity.x < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y);
}
```

Swift :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureCellAction))
    cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    return cell
}

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let velocity : CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: tblView)
    if velocity.x < 0 {
        return false
    }
    return abs(Float(velocity.x)) > abs(Float(velocity.y))
}

@objc func panGestureCellAction(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)  {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: tblView)
    if recognizer.view?.frame.origin.x ?? 0 < 0 {
        return
    }
    recognizer.view?.center = CGPoint(
        x: (recognizer.view?.center.x ?? 0) + translation.x,
        y: (recognizer.view?.center.y ?? 0))
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
    if (recognizer.view?.frame.origin.x ?? 0) > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            recognizer.view?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: recognizer.view?.frame.origin.y ?? 0, width: recognizer.view?.frame.size.width ?? 0, height: recognizer.view?.frame.size.height ?? 0)
        })
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        let x = recognizer.view?.frame.origin.x ?? 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            recognizer.view?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: recognizer.view?.frame.origin.y ?? 0, width: recognizer.view?.frame.size.width ?? 0, height: recognizer.view?.frame.size.height ?? 0)
        } completion: { (finished) in
            if x > ((recognizer.view?.frame.size.width ?? 0) / 2) {
                self.txtChat.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using your swift code ... but it disturbing the scroll of `UITableView` ... sometimes its works and sometimes it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

I created the Swipe Gesture using swift 5 on Xcode 14.2

Following is my code in `UITableViewCell` to perform swiping...

```
//declare the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` 
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

//a call back to notify the swipe in `cellForRowAt` as follow.
var replyCallBack : ( () -> Void)?

//this view perform swiping in cell
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView! 

 override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
           
            //set up your UI 

            setSwipeGesture() //register gesture 
  }


func setSwipeGesture(){
        // Add the swipe gesture and set the direction to the right or left according to your needs 
        swipeGesture.direction = .right
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        
        // Add a target to the swipe gesture to handle the swipe
        swipeGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
 }


@objc func handleSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            // Animate the action view onto the screen when the user swipes right
            if gesture.direction == .right {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
                    self.messageContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.contentView.frame.width / 2.5, y: 0)

                    // Schedule a timer to restore the cell after 0.2 seconds or change it according to your needs
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false) { (_) in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                            self.messageContainerView.transform = .identity

                            //callback to notify in cellForRowAt 
                            self.replyCallBack!()

                            //your code when 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Animate the action view off the screen when the user swipes left

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.messageContainerView.transform = .identity
            }
        }
    }
```

you can change the animation duration according to your need or `.right` to `.left` animation...  in this case, I only performed the right swipe...